# How to create a variable of list of strings in stored procedure and how to use it in another query?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to save a list of string in a variable which in turn i want to use it in another query.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE store_validated_sku_id
    (variable_sku_id OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT vsku.SKU_ID INTO variable_sku_id 
    FROM CHELSEA_prdcataloga.vs_sku_discont_details_test discontd
    JOIN CHELSEA_prdcataloga.vsx_dcs_sku vsku ON discontd.SWAP_SKU = vsku.JDA_SKU_ID 
    JOIN CHELSEA_prdcataloga.auto_ship_view bcc ON bcc.sku_id = vsku.SKU_ID 
    WHERE vsku.web_eligible = 1 
      AND vsku.discontinued = 0 
      AND bcc.auto_ship_eligible = 1;

    dbms_output.put_line('variable_sku_id = '|| variable_sku_id);
END store_validated_sku_id;
```

I want `variable_sku_id`  to be as list of string and want to use it in another query.

Comment: See the `LISTAGG` function.

Comment: Thanks @TenG,it worked. i replaced SELECT vsku.SKU_ID INTO variable_sku_id  with SELECT LISTAGG(vsku.SKU_ID,',') within group (order by vsku.SKU_ID) INTO variable_sku_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create procedure store_validated_sku_id(variable_sku_id OUT VARCHAR2)
 as
BEGIN
  SELECT listagg(vsku.sku_id, ',') within group(order by vsku.sku_id)
    INTO variable_sku_id
    FROM chelsea_prdcataloga.vs_sku_discont_details_test discontd
    JOIN chelsea_prdcataloga.vsx_dcs_sku vsku ON discontd.swap_sku = vsku.jda_sku_id
    JOIN chelsea_prdcataloga.auto_ship_view bcc ON bcc.sku_id = vsku.sku_id
   WHERE vsku.web_eligible = 1        
     AND vsku.discontinued = 0
     AND bcc.auto_ship_eligible = 1;

  dbms_output.put_line('variable_sku_id = ' || variable_sku_id);

END store_validated_sku_id;
```